# setOnMapClickListener deprecated method of Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, deprecated, mapbox-android

I am using the Mapbox API and its setOnMapClickListener is deprecated. I haven't found any other way to use the `onMapClick` method; is there another way?

Comment: i upvoted you answer bro thanks for help @Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setOnMapClickListener` was deprecated in release 5.3.0 in favor of `addOnMapClickListener`.

Source: [API Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/6.5.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.html#setOnMapClickListener-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener-)